# how to reduce execution time of python program which uses function plt.plot and plt.show()

Tags: python

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as m
import numpy as np
from pylab import imshow, show, get_cmap
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
array1 = cv2.imread('appler.jpg')
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(array1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image=gray1
cMap = ListedColormap(['white', 'yellow', 'green', 'red'])
fig =plt.figure()
plt.plot = plt.imshow(image)
data = np.clip(image, 1, 5)
im = imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cMap)
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ticks=[1,2,3,4,5])
im.set_clim(vmin=1,vmax=5)
plt.show()
```

this program excecutes correctly but takes a lot of time...........
is there any way to reduce the run time of this program

Comment: What parts are taking the longest?

Comment: i need this program to get excecuted within 1 or 2 seconds of time.......

Comment: first portion of the program and fig = plt.figure() takes time..... similarly plt.show()